# Get a value from two tables

Tags: sql, laravel, join, pdo

I am trying to get the value of the colum "name" from the clubs table.

**First table:(Clubs)**

- id*
- name ***(what i need!!!)***
- email
- password

**Second table:(club_posts)**

- id
- club_id*
- zip_id
- kategory
- type
- stadt
- plz

**Controller:**

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $zip = $request->input('zip');

        $users = Post::where('zip_id', 'like', $zip)
                        ->orderBy('date')
                        ->paginate(25);

        $clubs = ClubPost::where('zip_id', 'like', $zip)
                        ->orderBy('updated_at')
                        ->paginate(25);

        $city = Zip::where('zip_code', 'like', $zip)
                        ->value('city');
```

**This is my query:**

```
        $names = Club::select('name')
                        ->leftJoin('club_posts', 'club_id', '=', 'clubs.id')
                        ->get();
```

```
        dd($names);
  
        return view('search.result', compact('users', 'clubs', 'city', 'names'));
    }
```

The result is an array with ten values, but need only one.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a relation club in you ClubPost Model so that you can access the club of that club post using the relation.

ClubPost Model

```
public function club(){
   return $this->belongsTo(App\Club::class, 'club_id', 'id');
}
```

Now if you want to access the **name(or any other property)** of the club for a club post, you can use the club relation.

In your blade, you'd be looping over the $club_posts.

```
@foreach($club_posts as $club_post)

    {{ $club_post->club->name }}
@endforeach
```

Also, eager load the club relation in your controller.

```
$club_posts = ClubPost::with('club')
                        ->where('zip_id', 'like', $zip)
                        ->orderBy('updated_at')
                        ->paginate(25);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupBy to return single result

```
$names = Club::select('name')
               ->leftJoin('club_posts', 'club_id', '=', 'clubs.id')
               ->groupBy('name')
               ->get();
```